# Pandas: convert two times to datetime, then take the difference and display back as only times

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following toy Pandas dataframe named `df`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'begin' : ['08:00', '10:00', '14:00'], 
                   'end'   : ['14:00', '17:00', '22:00']})

begin     end      
08:00     14:00    
10:00     17:00    
14:00     22:00
```

I would like to calculate the difference between the `begin` and `end` times (in hours).  Here is my attempt:

```
df['begin'] = pd.to_datetime(df['begin'])
df['end'] = pd.to_datetime(df['end'])

df['diff_hours'] = (df['end'] - df['begin']) / pd.Timedelta(hours=1)
```

This yields:

```
    begin                  end                     diff_hours
0   2021-12-28 08:00:00    2021-12-28 14:00:00     6
1   2021-12-28 10:00:00    2021-12-28 17:00:00     7
2   2021-12-28 14:00:00    2021-12-28 22:00:00     8
```

This approach takes the **current date**.  I would like to strip the current date from the output above, such that the `df` becomes:

```
    begin          end          diff_hours
0   08:00:00       14:00:00     6
1   10:00:00       17:00:00     7
2   14:00:00       22:00:00     8
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance you can give!

##################################

**EDIT**

Inspired by an earlier comment by @BENY and the solution provided by @wwnde, I used the following to solve this:

```
df['diff_hours'] = ((pd.to_datetime(df['end']) - pd.to_datetime(df['begin'])) / pd.Timedelta(hours=1))
```

Comment: No, I do not care about seconds (I only care about hours and minutes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Coerce the time to datetime, substract and convert outcome to hours

```
   df['diff_hours']=(pd.to_datetime(df['end'], format="%H:%M")-pd.to_datetime(df['begin'], format="%H:%M")).astype('timedelta64[m]')/60



 begin    end  diff_hours
0  08:00  14:00         6.0
1  10:00  17:00         7.0
2  14:00  22:00         8.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert date time to time like this:

```
df['begin'] = df['begin'].dt.time
df['end'] = df['end'].dt.time
```

```
      begin       end  diff_hours
0  08:00:00  14:00:00         6.0
1  10:00:00  17:00:00         7.0
2  14:00:00  22:00:00         8.0
```

Comment: Using this, I get `AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values`.  Do we need to first convert the times to datetime objects?

Comment: That's odd.  Are you executing all the statements in your question in the same sequence, followed by the two in this answer?